# how to make clipboard with Paragraphs of text in using daisyui?

Tags: svelte, clipboard, sveltekit, daisyui, pocketbase

I want to make a clipboard in my svelte-kit app. I am using daisy ui and tailwind-css.

I tried using `<textarea>` component and made it (readonly) but the problem i am having is it disregards paragraph and structure of the text (it is a email body containing 3 paragraphs) and it combines all paragraph in one.

how can I make a clipboard component without loosing the paragraph structure?

Moving to other component library is no feasible since very large portion if the app is using daisy-ui.